# input data to structure with scanf on c

Tags: c, input, struct

People, i've tried to understand how to input and print the data to structure with terminal by scanf function...but it`s not working. I'm going to have my exam on c, and it is hard to understand for me.
My code is bellow. When i run the code it cause some warning, like

> First-chance exception at 0x59473FD4 (msvcr120d.dll) in Project2.exe:
> 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00749000.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct icx 
{
    char nameprod[20]; 
    int year; 
};

struct icx a;

int main(){
    printf("Enter the data:\n");
    scanf_s("%s%d", a.nameprod, &a.year);
    printf("%s%d", a.nameprod, a.year);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Please I need your help.

Comment: Read the [scanf_s manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-160): *Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require you to specify buffer sizes for some parameters. Specify the sizes for all c, C, s, S, or string control set [] parameters. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter. It immediately follows the pointer to the buffer or variable.*

Comment: The proper answer to this is "don't use scanf". Unless you're reading a ctags file it's basically never the right choice. Read the whole input and then split it up yourself.

Comment: How can i read the whole input?

Comment: Guys, thanx for your attention. I`ve looked for the scanf_s manual and use (unsigneg)_countof()...and it will helped me. Have a nice weekend to you all!